# How to get the current url in phoenix framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I would like to know the current url with elixir / phoenix framework, how I can get this ?

**Edit #1**:

My nginx config file:

```
server {
        client_max_body_size 100M;

        listen  80;

        server_name *.example.dev *.example2.dev

        access_log  /usr/local/var/log/nginx/baby-access.log;
        error_log   /usr/local/var/log/nginx/baby-error.log;


        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
        }
}
```

Code:

```
Atom.to_string(conn.scheme) <> "://" <> (Enum.into(conn.req_headers, %{}) |> Map.get("host")) <> conn.request_path
```

That example returns http://127.0.0.1:4000/, I would like to get http://www.example.dev/

I'm in development mode.

Comment: You could keep the original header in the nginx proxy server. ```location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000; proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }```

Comment: but i think if you run in production mode, one of the other methods will work.

Comment: glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 17):

If you are interested only in the request path you can use `conn.request_path` which holds a value like `"/users/1"`.

To get the URL including the host you can use

```
MyApp.Router.Helpers.url(conn) <> conn.request_path
```

which would return a result like `"http://localhost:4000/users/1"`.

Comment: I don't want localhost:4000, I want the domain name I configured in Nginx. Make sense ?

Comment: `conn.request_path` returns just the path, without the query string, so it is not the full or even relative URL.

Comment: @JeremieGes have Nginx pass the request URI as a header in the proxy

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Phoenix.Controller.current_url/1](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#current_url/1):

```
current_url(conn)
```

The endpoint configuration will define the URL:

```
config :my_app_web, MyAppWeb.Endpoint, url: [host: "example.com"]
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure which is the best method.

But maybe something like this as an illustration inside `IndexController`.

```
  def index(conn, params) do

    url_with_port = Atom.to_string(conn.scheme) <> "://" <>
                    conn.host <> ":" <> Integer.to_string(conn.port) <>
                    conn.request_path

    url =  Atom.to_string(conn.scheme) <> "://" <>
            conn.host <>
            conn.request_path

    url_phoenix_helper = Tester.Router.Helpers.index_url(conn, :index, params["path"]) # <-- This assumes it is the IndexController which maps to index_url/3

    url_from_endpoint_config = Atom.to_string(conn.scheme) <> "://" <>
                               Application.get_env(:my_app, MyApp.Endpoint)[:url][:host]  <>
                               conn.request_path

url_from_host_header =  Atom.to_string(conn.scheme) <> "://" <> 
                        (Enum.into(conn.req_headers, %{}) |> Map.get("host")) <> 
                        conn.request_path

    text = ~s"""

      url_with_port :: #{url_with_port}

      url :: #{url}

      url_phoenix_helper :: #{url_phoenix_helper}

      url_from_endpoint_config :: #{url_from_endpoint_config}

      url_from_host_header :: #{url_from_host_header}
    """

    text(conn, text)
  end
```

Comment: Well for the host I'm getting 127.0.0.1 than the "nginx" url, isn't possible to get that data ?

Comment: Are you running your server in `dev` mode or `prod` mode? I'd imagine one of the above options should work in `prod` mode?

Comment: if none of those are working, you can get the host from the request headers. ```Atom.to_string(conn.scheme) <> "://" <>
                               (Enum.into(conn.req_headers, %{}) |> Map.get("host")) <>
                               conn.request_path```But I don't think this is a good way to do it. Using the phoenix helpers is probably the way to go alongside running the app in production mode. See `config/prod.exs`

Comment: keep the original header in the nginx proxy server. ```proxy_set_header Host $host;```

Answer (score 0):

The function [`Plug.Conn.request_url`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/1.14.0/Plug.Conn.html#request_url/1) bring all details for the request

The [answer from @dan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47858691/6104353) is more correct in my opinion, but depending where are you using it might not be the right choice in terms of separation of concerns

e.g. if you are attempt to use in the Phoenix.View sounds weird to use a Controller function

The [solution from @ventsislaf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37736507/6104353) does not work for me due the behavior of my platform provider causing to point to a internal host of the provider not my configured CNAME

I would go for use the Plug function or maybe better replicate it where do you need, in my case `MyAppWeb.LayoutView` sounded a better solution because I won't show port and query parameters