# How do I setup a subdomain to serve all API traffic?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, render.com

I have a single web app running on a single instance on `example.com`. It has an API at `example.com/api`.

I want to set up a subdomain `api.example.com` and serve all API traffic from that subdomain.

How do I serve all API traffic from the subdomain while running off a single instance?

Comment: To clarify, you're not asking about how to set up the proper DNS records, but rather how to make a single Elixir app handle requests differently depending on the domain requested, yes?   Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735351/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-phoenix-framework

Comment: I'm open to handling this at the DNS level. The end result should be the same, a single instance of my app handling both web traffic and API requests from different subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up at router level. Take a look at this example
https://blog.gazler.com/blog/2015/07/18/subdomains-with-phoenix/

In short.

- Define an `APIRouter` where it has all API related routes.
- Put a plug at app `endpoint` right before the main router to handle requests to the `APIRouter`.

```
# endpoint.ex
plug YourApp.Plug.Subdomain, YourApp.APIRouter
plug YourApp.Router
```

The logic for the plug should be:

```
defmodule YourApp.Plug.Subdomain do
  import Plug.Conn

  @doc false
  def init(default), do: default

  @doc false
  def call(conn, router) do
    case get_subdomain(conn.host) do
      subdomain when subdomain == "api" ->
        # If it is from API -> initialize/match current request to APIRouter
        conn
        |> router.call(router.init({}))
        |> halt()

      _ -> conn # If it's not -> continue with current AppRouter
    end
  end
  
  # A function to get current subdomain or try to match it, your call.
  defp get_subdomain(host) do
    root_host = Subdomainer.Endpoint.config(:url)[:host]
    String.replace(host, ~r/.?#{root_host}/, "")
  end
end
```